# recording data from html5 widget

Tags: javascript, html, web-widget

I am trying to form a quiz widget using HTML5. At the end of the quiz, I have to record the results of it when the user hits the "send" button. The user doesn't need to see the records.
How should I do this? Can I use html5 or do I need javascript or something else for recording?

Answer (score 0):

Its good you are using HTML5 but are you really using html5 elements? if yes then its OK but as understood the more of your widget will be javascirpt driven, you can store the entries send to database using ajax.

Thanks
Dhiraj

Comment: I found the code I am using from internet and I am trying to convert it to a suitable form now. As you understand, I have only a little info about html5. The code uses html5 canvas and some functions for the questions, answers and results. Also, all of the code written in "<html>" statement.